# Hide Registration form, show another form after success

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to hide the registration form, after submit and all checks comes success, then hide this form, then show another one for choose product form.
Been trying to see if the settimeout would do the trick, but only shows a white blank page after success.

Anyone got any idea? Thanks =)

```
setTimeout('$(".signin-form").fadeOut(500, function(){ $(".ChooseProductForm").fadein(500); }); ',2000);
```

Sorry, i misunderstood the hole jQuery, so read my way up to understand a bit more and fixed this question while many other problems as well :-)

Comment: I have an idea, Google `Ajax` or read [ask]

Comment: form, what form? I also don't see relevance for the php tag

Comment: after success     $('#form-id').hide();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good finding for syntax error in function parameters.
But my suggestion is if you are using fadeIn and fadeOut animation methods, setTimeOut will bring unwanted delays to users. So instead using timer function just do animation to hide and display contents.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is not correct. See below, corrected code.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".signin-form").fadeOut(500, function() {
        $(".ChooseProductForm").fadein(500);
    });
}, 2000);
```

Note: I assume you call this code inside `done()` or `success` Ajax method.